# применение TapGesture на группу image =?

Tags: swift

применение TapGesture на группу image = ?
-можно ли как-то обойти применение к каждому имаже своего TapGesture или это
 заведомая обреченность...

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял что вам нужно, делайте так:

```
//создаете какой-то жест, который нужно отслеживать
let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageWasTapped))
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false

//и добавляете его всем вашим UIImageView
let image = UIImageView()
let image2 = UIImageView()
[image, image2].forEach {
    $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    $0.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Все будет приходить сюда

```
@objc func imageWasTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender)
}
```

Comment: спс... попробую...@onmotion